# Android hardware camera fire intent after onPictureTaken

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I have implemented my own camera preview layout and functionality. Anyway, when I press the button to take a picture it calls the `onPictureTaken` method, but the `Intent` is not fired. The `Intent` is declared correctly in the manifest file.

Here is my code and I hope someone knows what to do here in order to fire my `Intent`.

```
public class TakePicture extends Activity {
private Preview mPreview;
private Camera mCamera;
private int numberOfCameras;
private int defaultCameraId;
private Context context;

AutoFocusCallback myAutoFocusCallback = new AutoFocusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onAutoFocus(boolean arg0, Camera arg1) {
        // buttonTakePicture.setEnabled(true);
    }
};

PictureCallback myPictureCallback_JPG = new PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {
        //savePicture(arg0);

        Intent ia = new Intent(context, PreviewPhoto.class);
        ia.putExtra("groupId", 1);
        ia.putExtra("image", arg0);
        startActivity(ia);
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
    setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON,
            R.drawable.zzz_logo);
    context = this;

    mPreview = new Preview(this);
    setContentView(mPreview);
    LayoutInflater controlInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
    View viewControl = controlInflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_control,
            null);
    LayoutParams layoutParamsControl = new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    this.addContentView(viewControl, layoutParamsControl);

    numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    CameraInfo cameraInfo = new CameraInfo();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
        Camera.getCameraInfo(i, cameraInfo);
        if (cameraInfo.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
            defaultCameraId = i;
        }
    }

    Button buttonTakePicture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.takepicture);
    buttonTakePicture.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null,
                    myPictureCallback_JPG);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    mCamera = Camera.open(defaultCameraId);
    mPreview.setCamera(mCamera);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (mCamera != null) {
        mPreview.setCamera(null);
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }
}

 public void determineDisplayOrientation() {
        CameraInfo cameraInfo = new CameraInfo();
        Camera.getCameraInfo(defaultCameraId, cameraInfo);

        int rotation = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        int degrees  = 0;

        switch (rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                degrees = 0;
                break;

            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                degrees = 90;
                break;

            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                degrees = 180;
                break;

            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                degrees = 270;
                break;
        }

        int displayOrientation;

        if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            displayOrientation = (cameraInfo.orientation + degrees) % 360;
            displayOrientation = (360 - displayOrientation) % 360;
        } else {
            displayOrientation = (cameraInfo.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
        }

        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(displayOrientation);
    }

private void savePicture(byte[] data) {
    File pictureFileDir = getDir();
    if (!pictureFileDir.exists() && !pictureFileDir.mkdirs()) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Can't create directory to save image.",
          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddhhmmss");
    String date = dateFormat.format(new Date());
    String photoFile = "Picture_" + date + ".jpg";
    String filename = pictureFileDir.getPath() + File.separator + photoFile;
    File pictureFile = new File(filename);

    try {
      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
      fos.write(data);
      fos.close();
      Toast.makeText(context, "New Image saved:" + photoFile,
          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception error) {
      Toast.makeText(context, "Image could not be saved.",
          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

private File getDir() {
    File sdDir = Environment
      .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    return new File(sdDir, "Captoom");
  }

class Preview extends ViewGroup implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private final String TAG = "Preview";

    SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    Size mPreviewSize;
    List<Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;
    Camera mCamera;

    Preview(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mSurfaceView = new SurfaceView(context);
        addView(mSurfaceView);

        mHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        mSurfaceView.setOnClickListener(new LinearLayout.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //buttonTakePicture.setEnabled(false);
                mCamera.autoFocus(myAutoFocusCallback);
            }
        });
    }

    public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
        mCamera = camera;
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mSupportedPreviewSizes = mCamera.getParameters()
                    .getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            requestLayout();
        }
    }

    public void switchCamera(Camera camera) {
        setCamera(camera);
        //determineDisplayOrientation();

        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException caused by setPreviewDisplay()", exception);
        }

        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
        requestLayout();
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(),
                widthMeasureSpec);
        final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(),
                heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

        if (mSupportedPreviewSizes != null) {
            mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width,
                    height);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        if (changed && getChildCount() > 0) {
            final View child = getChildAt(0);

            final int width = r - l;
            final int height = b - t;

            int previewWidth = width;
            int previewHeight = height;
            if (mPreviewSize != null) {
                previewWidth = mPreviewSize.width;
                previewHeight = mPreviewSize.height;
            }

            if (width * previewHeight > height * previewWidth) {
                final int scaledChildWidth = previewWidth * height
                        / previewHeight;
                child.layout((width - scaledChildWidth) / 2, 0,
                        (width + scaledChildWidth) / 2, height);
            } else {
                final int scaledChildHeight = previewHeight * width
                        / previewWidth;
                child.layout(0, (height - scaledChildHeight) / 2, width,
                        (height + scaledChildHeight) / 2);
            }
        }
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            if (mCamera != null) {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            }
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException caused by setPreviewDisplay()", exception);
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        }
    }

    private Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
        double targetRatio = (double) w / h;
        if (sizes == null)
            return null;

        Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        int targetHeight = h;

        for (Size size : sizes) {
            double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
            if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE)
                continue;
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }

        if (optimalSize == null) {
            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Size size : sizes) {
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }
        return optimalSize;
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
        requestLayout();

        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: 1. Put some log statements in to be 100% sure `onPictureTaken` is called. 2. Try `Intent ia = new Intent(TakePicture.this, PreviewPhoto.class);`

Comment: onPictureTaken is called cause I checked this. The new Intent instantiation mode doesn't solve anything.

Comment: If `onPictureTaken` is called, you will either see `onCreate` of `PreviewPhoto`, or an `Exception`. Add a log statement to `onCreate` and check the logs and tell us what you are seeing.

Comment: The onCreate of PreviewPhoto is not called. Instead in my logs I get a failed binder transaction. I think that the line ia.putExtra("image", arg0) is causing this error. I must pass the image path, not the byte[] of data to the new intent :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line ia.putExtra("image", arg0) is causing the error failed binder transaction. I must pass the image path, not the byte[] of data to the new intent :)

Comment: You may want to save the data to globals if you want to avoid extra disk writes. Like I did here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43459956/649379