# Bitmap crash activity

Tags: java, android, arrays, parse-platform, android-bitmap

I am trying to transfer byte[] to another intent and turn it into Bitmap,However its crash my app without errors in logcat,the logcat just restart.
Some of the photos are working fine and some of them just crash the activity.

If I don't get the image value,only the other data,its working great,but when I try to get the image too, its restart.

First I am getting the image byte[] from parse and I transfer it through intent to another activity and convert it to bitmap.

Getting data from parse:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Feed");
query.orderByDescending("createdAt");

query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {

        if (e == null){

                for (ParseObject allData : objects) {


                image = (ParseFile) allData.get("Pictures");


                if (image == null){
                    Log.e("Image", "NULL");
                }else{
                    image.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {

                            if (e == null){


                                date = allData.getCreatedAt();
                                DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss\nyyyy-MM-dd");
                                reportDate = df.format(date);

                                arrayList.add(new MyData(reportDate,allData.getString("UserName"),allData.getString("BussinessName"),data));

                            }


                            adapter = new MyAdapter(FeedActivity.this, arrayList);
                            feedListView.setAdapter(adapter);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                   
                        }
                    });
                }

            }


            }

        }

});
```

Sending the byte[] to another activity:

```
feedListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        Intent intent = new Intent(FeedActivity.this, BusinessDetails.class);

            MyData data = (MyData) adapter.getItem(position);

            String BusinessNamePage = data.getBusinessName();
            String DatePage = data.getDate();
            String UserNamePage = data.getUserName();
            byte[] PicturePage = data.getPicture();

            intent.putExtra("image",PicturePage);
            intent.putExtra("BussinessName", BusinessNamePage);
            intent.putExtra("Date", DatePage);
            intent.putExtra("username", UserNamePage);

            startActivity(intent);



    }
});
```

Getting the byte[] in another activity and convert it to bitmap:

```
public class BusinessDetails extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_business_details);

        ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageViewTitle);
        TextView businessName = findViewById(R.id.businessNameDetailTitle);
        TextView userName = findViewById(R.id.userNameValue);
        TextView date = findViewById(R.id.dateValue);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        byte[] image = intent.getByteArrayExtra("image");
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp));

        businessName.setText(intent.getStringExtra("BussinessName"));
        date.setText(intent.getStringExtra("Date"));
        userName.setText(intent.getStringExtra("username"));

    }


}
```

Thank you !

EDIT: The error - https://ibb.co/ngJGWBJ

Comment: Do you know which line causes your app crash?

Comment: Unfortunately I dont, but I think its the byte[] to Bitmap causing this..

Comment: well, you can set a lot of "Log.d(...);" in every line and track them, just to be sure

Comment: Okay I changed the filter on logcat so I can now see the error:
https://ibb.co/ngJGWBJ

Answer (score 1):

Okay so finally I got it working.

The picture I was trying to transfer through intent was too big and that was the reason some of the photos were fine and some of them crashed my app.

To solve it I used this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45149923/14446860